# What does всевеликий mean?

Tags: лексикон, диалект

I have encountered "всевеликое войско донское", but what exactly does it mean in Russian? Perhaps it is dialectal? Can it be seen in other context?

Answer (score 8):

It's a Church Slavonic calque from Greek *παμμέγιστοσ* ("the greatest of all").

The Greek word had been used as a title of several Christian saints in medieval Greek literature and was calqued by Slavonic translators.

The tradition of using a positive Slavic adjective and the prefix *все-* to form a superlative form can be also observed in words like *всеблагий* ("the kindest of all"), *всемилостивый* ("the most merciful of all"), *всепетая* ("the most praised of all") etc.

This pattern might be somewhat confusing because words like *всемогущий* ("omnipotent") and *всеведущий* ("omniscient") don't mean "the most knowledgeable / potent of all", but rather "the one who knows / can do everything".

Answer (score 4):

**Всевеликий** [means](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) 'great to the utmost extent', it is often used in religious contexts and refers to the Lord, **Всевеликий Господь**, 'God the Almighty'. In the name of the **Всевеликое Войско Донское** this word is [also translated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Republic) into English as 'almighty', 'the Almighty Don Host'.